# How do I read properties from my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails, and I have no idea how to make properties in a settings file that I can read from my rails application. I have this code:

```
Time.now.advance(:days => -7)
```

I would like it to be configurable, so that I can configure it to be (:months => -2) or what ever I like. How do I do this in rails?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this hash in one of your configuration files (in `config/environments/development.rb` or `config/environment.rb`, for example):

```
ADVANCE_SPAN = {:days => -7}
```

And then use it in your code

```
Time.now.advance(ADVANCE_SPAN)
```

Comment: And does my application re-read this property when changed, or do I have to restart the server?

Comment: @Neigaard It'll take you exactly 2 minutes to try and see.